# Incorporating knitr into your workflow

Tags: r, markdown, knitr

Just wondering, how do people incorporate knitr into their current workflow? I have a long, pre-existing .R file that reads in data, does the analysis, and at the end of the file I produce, say, a ggplot chart and a table summarizing my findings. I'd like to incorporate these into a document, either markdown or LaTeX. Should I rename my initial .R file to be a .Rmd file and put the knitr commands near the end? Should I create a new .Rmd file that creates the report, and somehow incorporate the analysis from the .R file? In other words, what are best practices for adding knitr output to my existing workflow?

Comment: You cannot simply rename the file and expect it to work as markdown/LaTeX shell around your code. See examples of what knitr actually does. http://yihui.name/knitr/demos/ I usually copy/paste parts of scripts into chunks which are part of the "knitr document" and interlace it with comments. (Printed) figures are automagically added to output.

Comment: Thanks, and let me be a little more explicit. I'd like to have this as automated as possible, to minimize manually cutting and pasting from one file to another. And part of the analysis is reading in large files, manipulating them, etc. Do I have to do this all over again in the .Rmd file? Isn't there a way to pass the final tables and figures from the .R file?

Comment: you could use [`spin()`](http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/stitch/)

Comment: Thanks for the spin() hint. Indeed, it looks like the shortest distance between a pre-existing .R file and a quick report.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use external sourcing to keep your scripts as your repository of code and your knitr document to call on it.  You would benefit from this approach.

For example, mark your existing code in your long .R script like this:

```
## @knitr Q5

all your data prep code

plotQ5 <- ggplot(your plot code

plotQ5
```

Then in your knitr document, with the suffix  .Rnw, have something like this code chunk

```
<<Q05, results='hide', echo = FALSE, include=FALSE>>=
@

<<Q05plot, fig.width=width, fig.height=height, fig.align="center", warning = FALSE, echo=FALSE>>=
plotQ05
@
```

Now, when you compile PDF for Latex knitr will source your code and plot from the script and output the PDF file with the plot in it.

Additionally, learn to cache large objects in knitr so that it does not need to read them in again if they have not changed.

Comment: Thanks! This looks very helpful. Let me take a closer look.

Comment: OK, accepted your answer. Thanks for pointing me towards this.

Comment: Much appreciated.  If you have other knitr questions, I would be glad to go offline or chat, since I am learning knitr/Latex and would welcome having someone else to share experiences with.

Comment: I may take you up on that. I have long experience with LaTeX, but I'm new to the R/Markdown/knitr world and need to get that going as soon as possible.

Comment: My pleasure.  What is the best way to connect?  By phone?  I am in Princeton, NJ, USA.